# Why doesn't npm start run electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have the following in package.json for several electron apps:

```
  "name": "my-app",  
  "version": "1.0.0",  
  "description": "",  
  "main": "main.js",  
      "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
      },
```

When I'd do `npm start` in the app folder, the corresponding app use to run. I just started getting the following output for all of my electron apps when using `npm start`:

> > electron .
>
> module.js:471
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25).
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/Users/me/electron/my-app/node_modules/.bin/electron:3:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! m1@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the m1@1.0.0 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.

However, I can do either of the following successfully on the command line:

```
electron main.js
electron .
```

Anyone know what might have broken the package.json script? Or some other suggestions?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Can you post your entire package.json?

Comment: Deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install fixed the issue.

Comment: should i be able to execute `electron index.js` or `electron .` in command prompt? i get the following error, `'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`, obviously due to Electron not being set to path. but i never needed to set Electron to path before ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delete the `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install`.

Comment: It still doesn't run the sample code when I run npm start

Comment: should i be able to execute `electron index.js` or `electron .` in command prompt? i get the following error, `'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`, obviously due to Electron not being set to path. but i never needed to set Electron to path before ???